# Lapack + c + matrix

Tags: matrix, lapack

Would you please help me understand how to call a Lapack routine? In particular, I want to call DTRTRI (Uplo, DIAG, N, DA, LDA, INFO).

Comment: I didn't know I speak French:)

Comment: This is an English website. Please post your question in English. You can use an online translator if necessary. Use the "edit" link at the bottom to update your question.

Answer (score 0):

Just use one of the existing [C language wrappers](https://www.google.com/#sclient=psy-ab&q=lapack+c+wrapper) for LAPACK (which itself is written in FORTRAN).

Specifically, try [lapwrapc](http://netlib.org/lapack/lapwrapc/index.html).

It has a C interface to DTRTRI defined in src/lapack_dtrtri.c

```
void lapack_dtrtri( const enum lapack_uplo_type uplo, 
                    const enum lapack_diag_type diag, 
                    const int n, 
                    double * a, 
                    const int lda, 
                    int * info )
```

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the source to the [Armadillo C++ Library](http://arma.sourceforge.net), which calls many Lapack functions.

Armadillo calls the Fortran functions directly from C++, without using any C language wrappers or converting the Fortran code.